# How to hide parent div based on css class children and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some trouble figuring out the condition for hiding some div's. My code looks like this

```
<div>          
      <div>
        <label id="radio" for="select_radio">Select x</label>
      </div>
      <div>
          <div>
              <input name="select_radio" value="Yes" id="yes" type="radio">
              <label id="label_radio_yes" for="yes">Yes </label>
          </div>
          <div>
              <input name="select_radio" value="No" id="no" type="radio">
              <label id="label_radio_no" for="no">No </label>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="grandparent"> 
    <p>I am the grandparent</p>
    <div class="parent"> 
        <p>I am the parent</p>
        <div class="child">
            <p>I am the child</p>
            <input class="child" value="Y" id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox">
            <label id="label_2" for="checkbox_2" class="child">Add another</label>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grandparent"> 
    <p>I am the grandparent</p>
    <div class="parent"> 
        <p>I am the parent</p>
        <div class="child">
            <p>I am the child</p>
            <input class="child" value="Y" id="checkbox_3" type="checkbox">
            <label id="label_3" for="checkbox_3" class="child">Add another </label>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grandparent"> 
    <p>I am the grandparent</p>
    <div class="parent"> 
        <p>I am the parent</p>
        <div class="child">
            <p>I am the child</p>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

What i'm trying to achieve is hiding the grandparent (from the dom) when:

- radiobutton yes is selected
- grandparent has a "child" child class
- checkbox in div is not selected

Basically, show second div if radio is yes and checkbox in the first div is selected. And show the third div is checkbox in second div is selected.

Hiding everything works by doing

```
if ($("input[name='select_radio']:checked").val() == 'No') {
    $(".child").parent(".parent").parent(".grandparent").hide();
}
```

Comment: Trying to hide the grandparent div, will hide everything nested in it. There is no way to hide the grandparent div and still show the child div within that grandparent element. Now with that out of the way lets look at the logic:

You want to say if label_radio_yes === true,
Show first grandparent with nested checkbox.

If first grandparent with child checkbox === checked,
show second grandparent with nested checkbox.

If second grandparent with child checkbox === checked,
show third grandparent with nested checkbox.

Is that what you are wanting to do?

Comment: Well, the third div does not have a checkbox and I don't want to hide the grandparent when the child needs to be shown. But yes that is wat I want.

Comment: There is a way to hide grandparent and at the same time still show the child and/or grandchild but the logic eludes me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first Snippet is CSS only. The layout needed changing to accommodate the use of the [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and [`~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) sibling selector. The second Snippet uses jQuery. Although the HTML layout isn't altered (`#relationship` being the exception), I added comments as suggestions to better markup. BTW, if you use radio buttons, it's always better to establish one of them as checked by default (with the exception being a quiz answer).

**Details are commented in both Snippets**

#### CSS Version

```css
input,
label {
  font: inherit;
}


/* Switch OFF override */

#no:checked+label+br+input+label+br~* {
  display: none
}


/* Switch OFF for content blocks */

br+div,
input[type=checkbox],
input[type=checkbox]+label {
  display: none;
}


/* Switch ON for content block */

input:checked+label+br+div {
  display: block;
}


/* Switch ON for content switch */

input:checked+label+br+div+input,
input:checked+label+br+div+input+label {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Presents the hierarchical relationship 
|| (optional) 
*/

div {
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Backgrounds (optional) */

.grandparent {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}

.parent {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
}

.child {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .3);
}
```

```html
<h3>CSS VERSION</h3>

<!--MAIN SWITCH BEGIN||||||-->
<label id="radio" for="select_radio">Select x</label><br/>

<!--#no is checked by defualt======-->
<input name="select_radio" value="No" id="no" type="radio" checked>
<label id="label_radio_no" for="no">No</label><br/>

<input name="select_radio" value="Yes" id="yes" type="radio">
<label id="label_radio_yes" for="yes">Yes</label><br/>
<!--MAIN SWITCH END||||||-->

<!--CONTENT BLOCKS BEGIN||||||-->
<!--Content Block 1======-->
<div class="grandparent">
  <p>I am the grandparent</p>
  <div class="parent">
    <p>I am the parent</p>
    <div class="child">
      <p>I am the child</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Content Switch 1======-->
<input class="child" value="Y" id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox">
<label id="label_2" for="checkbox_2" class="child">Add another</label><br/>

<!--Content Block 2======-->
<div class="grandparent">
  <p>I am the grandparent</p>
  <div class="parent">
    <p>I am the parent</p>
    <div class="child">
      <p>I am the child</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Content Switch 2======-->
<input class="child" value="Y" id="checkbox_3" type="checkbox">
<label id="label_3" for="checkbox_3" class="child">Add another </label><br/>

<!--Content Block 3======-->
<div class="grandparent">
  <p>I am the grandparent</p>
  <div class="parent">
    <p>I am the parent</p>
    <div class="child">
      <p>I am the child</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--CONTENT BLOCKS END||||||-->
```

#### jQuery Version

```js
/* Delegate the change event on #no and #yes
|| When one of them changes from checked to 
|| unchecked and vice versa...
*/
$('[name=select_radio]').on('change', function(e) {

  //...if `this` is #yes and it's checked...
  if ($(this).is('#yes:checked')) {

    //... show #relationship
    $('#relationship').show();

  } else {

    // Otherwise hide #relationship
    $('#relationship').hide();
  }

});

/* Delegate the change event to all checkboxes
|| with the class .child.
|| When it changes (checked or not)...
*/
$(':checkbox.child').on('change', function(e) {

  // Find it's closest ancestor .grandparent
  var grand = $(this).closest('.grandparent');

  /* If checked, then find the .grandparent 
  || after the .grandparent previously found and 
  || then show it.
  */
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    grand.next('.grandparent').show();
  } else {
    /* Otherwise find ALL .grandparents that proceed
    || previously found .grandparent and find their 
    || checkbox and uncheck it, then hide the .grandparent
    */
    grand.nextAll('.grandparent').hide().find(':checkbox.child').prop('checked', false);

  }
});
```

```css
input {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
}

.grandparent,
#relationship {
  display: none;
}

section>div:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}


/* Presents the hierarchical relationship (optional) */

div {
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Backgrounds (optional) */

.grandparent {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}

.parent {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
}

.child {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>jQuery Version</h3>

<!-- 
Comments with ✲ denotes uneccessary or inefficient 
markup and better alternatives
-->

<!-- ✲ input {display:inline-block} -->

<!-- ✲ remove div; margin-bottom and <br> on
#label_radio_no -->
<div>
  <!-- ✲ remove div; display:block or add <br> to #radio -->
  <div>
    <label id="radio" for="select_radio">Select x</label>
  </div>
  <!-- ✲ remove div; -->
  <div>
    <!-- ✲ remove div; add <br> and margin-bottom to     #label_radio_yes -->
    <div>
      <input name="select_radio" value="Yes" id="yes" type="radio">
      <label id="label_radio_yes" for="yes">Yes </label>
    </div>
    <!-- ✲ remove div; -->
    <div>
      <!--#no is checked by default -->
      <input name="select_radio" value="No" id="no" type="radio" checked>
      <label id="label_radio_no" for="no">No </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Wrap all content up in a container -->
<section id='relationship'>
  <div class="grandparent">
    <p>I am the grandparent</p>
    <div class="parent">
      <p>I am the parent</p>
      <div class="child">
        <p>I am the child</p>
        <input class="child" value="Y" id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox">
        <label id="label_2" for="checkbox_2" class="child">Add another</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grandparent">
    <p>I am the grandparent</p>
    <div class="parent">
      <p>I am the parent</p>
      <div class="child">
        <p>I am the child</p>
        <input class="child" value="Y" id="checkbox_3" type="checkbox">
        <label id="label_3" for="checkbox_3" class="child">Add another </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grandparent">
    <p>I am the grandparent</p>
    <div class="parent">
      <p>I am the parent</p>
      <div class="child">
        <p>I am the child</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) state of checkbox of `grandparent` using [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
if ($("input[name='select_radio']:checked").val() == 'Yes') {
    $(".grandparent:has(.child :checkbox:not(:checked))").hide();
}

if ($("input[name='select_radio']:checked").val() == 'No') {
    $(".grandparent:has(.child)").hide()
}
```

Note: In the snippet I have attached a event handler.

```js
$(":radio[name='select_radio']").on('change', function() {
  if ($("input[name='select_radio']:checked").val() == 'Yes') {
    $(".grandparent:has(.child :checkbox:not(:checked))").hide();
  }
  
  if ($("input[name='select_radio']:checked").val() == 'N0') {
    $(".grandparent:has(.child)").hide()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <label id="radio" for="select_radio">Select x</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input name="select_radio" value="Yes" id="yes" type="radio" checked>
      <label id="label_radio_yes" for="yes">Yes </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input name="select_radio" value="No" id="no" type="radio">
      <label id="label_radio_no" for="no">No </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grandparent">
  <p>I am the grandparent 1</p>
  <div class="parent">
    <p>I am the parent</p>
    <div class="child">
      <p>I am the child</p>
      <input class="child" value="Y" id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox">
      <label id="label_2" for="checkbox_2" class="child">Add another</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grandparent">
  <p>I am the grandparent 2</p>
  <div class="parent">
    <p>I am the parent</p>
    <div class="child">
      <p>I am the child</p>
      <input class="child" value="Y" id="checkbox_3" type="checkbox">
      <label id="label_3" for="checkbox_3" class="child">Add another </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grandparent">
  <p>I am the grandparent 3</p>
  <div class="parent">
    <p>I am the parent</p>
    <div class="child">
      <p>I am the child</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Selecting Yes should show only div 1. Selecting no should hide all three the divs.

Comment: @xseriff, Updated and we are here to guide you can modify the code to suite your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:
code isn't perfect, but I think the functionality is what you are looking for.

https://jsbin.com/haqaxuhesi/edit?html,js,output

```
var grandParents = $(".grandparent");
var subContainer = $(".sub-element");
var checkbox_0 = $("#checkbox_0");
var checkbox_1 = $("#checkbox_1");
var state = {
  open: false,
  checkbox_0: false,
  checkbox_1: false
};

//hide everything on load at first except for first element
grandParents.each( function(index, el){
  if(index === !0){
      $(this).hide();
  }
});

//check the radio value on pageload
checkRadioOnLoad();

//check inputs on pageload
checkInputs();


$(":radio[name='select_radio']").on('change', function() {

  var masterSelect = $(this).val();

  if(masterSelect === "Yes"){
    state.open = true;
  }else{
    state.open = false;
  }

  toggleContainer();

});

$(checkbox_0).on('change', function() {

  if(this.checked){
    state.checkbox_0 = true;
  }else{
    state.checkbox_0 = false;
  }

  //re-run check
  checkInputs();

});

$(checkbox_1).on('change', function() {

  if(this.checked){
    state.checkbox_1 = true;
  }else{
    state.checkbox_1 = false;
  }

  //re-run check
  checkInputs();

});

function toggleContainer(){
  if(state.open === true){
    subContainer.show();
  }else{
    subContainer.hide();
  }
}

function checkInputs(){

  if(state.checkbox_0){
    checkbox_1.parent().parent().parent().show();
  }else{
    checkbox_1.parent().parent().parent().hide();
  }

  if(state.checkbox_1){
    $(grandParents[2]).show();
  }else{
    $(grandParents[2]).hide();
  }
}


function checkRadioOnLoad(){
  if($("#radio_yes")){
    state.open = true;
  }else{
    state.open = false;
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <label id="radio" for="select_radio">Select x</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input name="select_radio" value="Yes" id="radio_yes" type="radio" checked>
      <label id="label_radio_yes" for="yes">Yes </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input name="select_radio" value="No" id="radio_no" type="radio">
      <label id="label_radio_no" for="no">No </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sub-element">
  <div class="grandparent">
  <p>I am the grandparent 1</p>
  <div class="parent">
    <p>I am the parent</p>
    <div class="child">
      <p>I am the child</p>
      <input class="child" value="Y" id="checkbox_0" type="checkbox">
      <label id="label_2" for="checkbox_2" class="child">Add another</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grandparent">
  <p>I am the grandparent 2</p>
  <div class="parent">
    <p>I am the parent</p>
    <div class="child">
      <p>I am the child</p>
      <input class="child" value="Y" id="checkbox_1" type="checkbox">
      <label id="label_3" for="checkbox_3" class="child">Add another </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grandparent">
  <p>I am the grandparent 3</p>
  <div class="parent">
    <p>I am the parent</p>
    <div class="child">
      <p>I am the child</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```